# AWS EC2 Self installed Mysql 5.7 is very very slow

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I self installed MySql 5.7 in AWS EC2 but when if i compare my local mysql server 5.7 performance to that of remotely connected AWS mysql server performance is very very slow its like 50 times slower. I am trying to access from spring boot application and fetching time is very slow compared to Local one.

Could you please help me.

Comment: What are the specs like, and what do you mean by slow? Slow to return results or the performance of the DB is poor

Comment: Slow to return the results

Comment: Have you looked at performance? Where is it located vs your local db? Are both servers the same specs regarding CPU, memory etc

Comment: To add on above comment, how are you accessing the DB? from Spring boot app? How both are connected? Are they in same network/AZ/Region?